# ExecutorService using invokeAll and timeout on callables thread not got terminated after timeout exception

Tags: java, multithreading, timeout, threadpool, executorservice

i try to set a timeout on the thread and expect that the executor to throw exception and prevent the thread form running that it terminating it but this not the case the timeout working find
but the thread do complete to execute.
how do i terminate the thread if it pass the timeout ?
this is my test code :

```
class ArithmeticBB implements ArithmeticManagerCallable.ArithmeticAction {
    @Override
    public String arithmetic(String n) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String ss  = n+" 2" + " ,Thread ID:" +Thread.currentThread().getId();
        return ss;
    }
}
public class ArithmeticManagerCallable {
    ExecutorService executor = null;
    private List<String> integerList = null;
    private List<String> myResult= Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    private int threadTimeOutInSec = 180;

    public ArithmeticManagerCallable(List<String> dataFromUser, int poolSize, int threadTimeOutInSec) {
        this.integerList =  dataFromUser;
        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(poolSize);
        this.threadTimeOutInSec = threadTimeOutInSec;
    }
    private void exec(ArithmeticAction arithmeticAction) {
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Iterator<String> iterator = integerList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            tempList.add(arithmeticAction.arithmetic(iterator.next()));
        }
        resultArray.addAll(tempList);
    }
    public List<String> invokerActions(List<ArithmeticAction> actions) throws
            InterruptedException {

        Set<Callable<String>> callables = new HashSet<>();
        for (final ArithmeticAction ac : actions) {
            callables.add(new Callable<String>() {
                public String call() throws Exception{
                    exec(ac);
                    return "done";
                }
            });
        }
        List<Future<String>> futures = executor.invokeAll(callables, this.threadTimeOutInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        return myResult;
    }
    public interface ArithmeticAction {
        String arithmetic(String n);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<ArithmeticManagerCallable.ArithmeticAction> actions = new ArrayList();
        actions.add(new ArithmeticBB());
        List<String> intData = new ArrayList<>();
        intData.add("1");

        ArithmeticManagerCallable arithmeticManagerCallable = new ArithmeticManagerCallable(intData,20,4);

        try {
            List<String> result = arithmeticManagerCallable.invokerActions(actions);
            System.out.println("***********************************************");
            for(String i : result) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Thread` does not complete it's execution after it exceeds the timeout.

For reference have a look at this example:

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(20);

List<Callable<String>> callableList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    final int identifier = i;
    callableList.add(()-> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 * identifier);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("I'm " + identifier + " and my sleep was interrupted.");
        }
        return identifier + " Hello World";
    });
}

try {
    List<Future<String>> futureList = executorService.invokeAll(callableList, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    for (Future<String> result : futureList) {
        System.out.println(result.get());
    }
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    System.out.println("Something went wrong while executing. This may help: " + e.getMessage());
} catch (CancellationException e) {
    System.out.println("Not all Futures could be received.");
} finally {
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, also i have wired thing that TimeoutException is never thrown from the 
executorService , how can i recognize it is timeout? InterruptedException  coming from the Thread. sleep not from the executorService it self

Comment: @user63898 `invokeAll` doesn't throw a `TimeoutException`. If you want to know if the future timed out before finishing its execution then you have to ask the Future directly via its second get-Method. -> `V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`

Comment: i like to catch the exception from type TimeoutException so that i have indicator .
i notice that is i do :
executor.submit(new Callable<String>() {
   public String call() throws Exception{
    exec(ac);
    return "done";
   }
  }).get(this.threadTimeOutInSec, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
it does throw the right exception from TimeoutException  
what is the difference between invokeAll and submiting one by one ?

Comment: @user63898 Put simply: Those are two different ways of implementation. `invokeAll` allows you to submit multiple `Callable`s at once. If you now what to execute them via `invokeAll` or submit them one by one is up to you as a developer.

Comment: Thanks i like to invoke what is not blocking